# Angular google maps not working with router-outlet

Tags: angular, typescript, agm-core

I am creating an application with a map as header (a global view) and an other map in the middle of the page, representing some detail views. I got this working [in this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysmwhv).

Now in order to minimize code duplication I would like to move the header map to a parent component, so I can reuse the global map header in multiple pages. I can do this via the Angular router (`children` tag). This means the following:

```
LayoutComponent (global view map) --> <router-outlet> --> HomeComponent (detail view map)
```

But somehow only the map in the child component loads. I have reproduced this behavior [in this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-degb4z).

Now I want to know, am I doing something wrong here? I cannot seem to find anything why this code shouldn't work.

---

**Versions**

- @agm/core `1.0.0`
- Angular `8.2.10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have some structure issues. In your FeatureModule, you load the HomeModule, and render the LayoutComponent. You also have the `<router-outlet>` in both the AppComponent and in the LayoutComponent. You also need to export certain components in their respective module in order to use them in other modules.

I have made some structure changes, where the FeatureModule loads the HomeComponent. The appComponent now use the `<app-layout>`-template, and the layout template will render the correct component according to its path, which is the HomeComponent for the empty path. Now, you have two maps, and the header will stay for all the different components you load.

Here is an attempt to solve what you had difficulties with: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/structure-map-module-component?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks, that works! But what if I want a route that doesn't use the layout component as it's parent? And why can't I nest router-outlets?

Comment: You can nest router outlets, but I think it is difficult to handle correctly. You need to structure your modules and components differently, instead of using app-layout in the app.component, you need to define another component, and let that one handle which routes should use app-layout and not.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Can you give me a code example of how this should be resolved if I wanted multiple types of parents, so not always the layout component as the parent?

Comment: I would probably have code in your app.component, that reads the current url (inject Router, and subscribe for navigationEnd-events), and then use *ngIf="displayLayout" on the layout component, and then *ngIf=!displayLayout" on the router-outlet for the template of app.component. There are other methods as well, and what works best for your app is up to you. `<app-layout *ngIf=".." /><router-outlet *ngIf="..." />`

Comment: If I add a language parameter to the parent route, the map is no longer loading. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/structure-map-module-component-mj4snr. if you add a language in the url, /en for example, the url rewrites to /en/home as expected, but the layout component is no longer loaded. Can you tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: As far as I can see, the layout component is actually loaded, but the map is not being displayed. Just try to add some text in the layout component, and you will see that it is actually there. Why the map is not rendering is a different problem though, but I am not sure why it is not being displayed.

Comment: I was looking around, and I added an `*ngIf="loaded"` to the map component, and added a `setTimeout()` in `ngOnInit()` making sure that the DOM is ready (using `ngAfterViewInit()` also works, and is actually a better solution), before trying ti add the map. https://stackblitz.com/edit/structure-map-module-component-oak2pk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201072/discussion-between-mr-wiseguy-and-john).